# How to in JMeter use regular expression extractor to fill request in loop

Tags: regex, jmeter, extractor

I've got simple test plan:

```
Jdbs Conection 
JDBC request
For Each Loop on jdbc response
  |-Regular Expression Extractor (Post processor)
  |-Soap Request where I need extracted value from Regular Expression Extractor
     |-Response assertion
```

The problem is when the first loop is executed. SOAP request is filled with name of variable from Regular Expression Extractor not the value. Can anyone tell me how to get around this problem?

[Edit] test plan screen

As you can see on the first image is showing jdbc  response data . On first position is value '22;1'. Second one is showing first soap request failed not a values but names of variables... Third one is showing second request filled correctly

http://postimg.org/image/owl5kue4v/

Below is screen when I add Debug Sampler to for each loop. In this situation first SOAP request is filled correctly.

http://postimg.org/image/aad3c0ngt/

My problem is how to get the same behavior like in second situation but without adding Debug Sampler?

BTW, Sorry for the images on an external server, but my rank is too low to add them here

Comment: Paste the snapshots of variable assignment and test plan

Comment: if variable contain variable name, then the extractor failed couldn't find a match. please show what you are entering in the config fields for regex extractor, or screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Your test plan should be in the format mentioned in the attached snapshot:

[image]

Hope this will help

Comment: It is not proper solution, because for each loop should going on rows responded by "req" and extract next values. And this values should be used to fill soap req. In your solution I will get only first row extracted or I something don't understand...

Comment: if you want for each request the values to be different, then put ***Match No.*** as "0" in your Regular expression extractor.  This will change the values randomly for each request. Or else if you want that the values should change in sequential order, then you need to write some code using Beanshell to achieve that.